# SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword"

Tags: flutter

error SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageUatRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword".

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleUatRelease'...                       135.9s
Gradle task assembleUatRelease failed with exit code 1

** use command
flutter build apk --flavor uat -dart-define=app.flavor=uat -t lib/namefile.dart --build-name=1.1.40 --build-number=46 --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --release

What should I do?, tried many ways

Comment: I delete key.properties and upload-keystore.jks, already new generate

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you have configured your keystore and build.gradle correctly? See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Take a look at the section 'Signing the app' and in particular how to set up the keystore and reference it via [project]/android/key.properties, which would contain the storePassword for your signing keystore.

Comment: I can not generate an upload key and keystore ,according to the method https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app ,  I'll double check key.properties